# i am unable to understand ,why only delete_node not working

Tags: python, django, jstree

These are three request geeting from user has following, create_node,rename_node are working fine but delete_node request not working.

```
requests:
[31/Aug/2018 17:00:53] "GET /buildknowledge/?operation=create_node&id=1&text=New+node HTTP/1.1" 200 16071
[31/Aug/2018 17:01:10] "GET /buildknowledge/?operation=rename_node&id=63&text=pkkkk HTTP/1.1" 200 16071
[31/Aug/2018 17:02:33] "GET /buildknowledge/?operation=delete_node&id=63 HTTP/1.1" 200 16071
```

views.py:

```
def basetest(request):
     cu_id = request.user.id
     if 'operation' in request.GET and "id" in request.GET and "text" in request.GET:
       operation = request.GET['operation']
       pid=request.GET['id']
       nodename=request.GET['text']
       if "create_node" == operation:
          p=Buildkb4.objects.create    (parent=pid,created_by=cu_id,text=nodename)
          p.save()
       elif "delete_node" == operation:
           Buildkb4.objects.filter(pk=pid).delete()
       elif "rename_node" == operation:
           Buildkb4.objects.filter(pk=pid).update(text=nodename)
   return render(request,"registration/basetest.html")
```

Comment: Because there is no `'text'` in your `request.GET`, so the first `if` fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note**: It is *not* a good idea to use GET requests to perform side-effects (like updating or removing records in a database). Therefore I would advice to change such requests to a POST, DELETE or PATCH. More information at the bottom of this post.

Based on the log you show, the delete call ships with two parameters in the *querystring*: `operation` and `id`. But the first `if` statement requires a `text` parameter as well:

```
def basetest(request):
     cu_id = request.user.id
     if 'operation' in request.GET and "id" in request.GET and "text" in request.GET:
       operation = request.GET['operation']
       pid=request.GET['id']
       nodename=request.GET['text']
       if "create_node" == operation:
          p=Buildkb4.objects.create    (parent=pid,created_by=cu_id,text=nodename)
          p.save()
       elif "delete_node" == operation:
           Buildkb4.objects.filter(pk=pid).delete()
       elif "rename_node" == operation:
           Buildkb4.objects.filter(pk=pid).update(text=nodename)
   return render(request,"registration/basetest.html")
```

So this will never reach the `elif "delete_node" == operation:` case.

You can fix this by making the check less restrictive, something like:

```
def basetest(request):
     cu_id = request.user.id
     if 'operation' in request.GET and "id" in request.GET:
       operation = request.GET['operation']
       pid=request.GET['id']
       if "delete_node" == operation:
           Buildkb4.objects.filter(pk=pid).delete()
       elif 'text' in request.GET:
           nodename=request.GET['text']
           if "create_node" == operation:
               p=Buildkb4.objects.create(parent=pid,created_by=cu_id,text=nodename)
           elif "rename_node" == operation:
               Buildkb4.objects.filter(pk=pid).update(text=nodename)
   return render(request,"registration/basetest.html")
```

Now it will work. **But** a GET is supposed to have *no* side-effects. So you are basically violating a contract of GET requests.

Typically a delete is performed through a POST, or a DELETE request, *not* a GET request. Changing data is also handled by a POST or PATCH request, again *not* a GET request. By making GET requests with side-effects, it can happen that robots (like search engines) will query the URL, and remove and/or update your data. This is probably *not* what you want.

Comment: I am working on jstree and following the documentation provided on  jstree.com , In examples they used GET method for delete operation also.

Comment: @confk: well like the HTTP specs say: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html "*GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval.*". By doing so, you do not follow the specifications, and this can result in for example search engines "triggering" deletion of parts of your database.